# NSMutableDictionary add object by sequence issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I added sequence in NSMutableDictionary by keys
Here is the key of Dictionary

```
New,
To Do,
Basic,
Advanced,
In Progress,
Done
```

But when I print NSMutableDictionary all keys then output was different

```
Advanced,
In Progress,
To Do,
New,
Done,
Basic
```

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Order is not guaranteed in a Dictionary, because you access/set element with a key, not an index.

Comment: Yes, I know we are not set order for this, If you have any other solution, Please let me know.

Comment: Use an array? What do you want to save/do exactly? What's the purpose?

Comment: User array is the last option for me, But I finding other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered collections. The sequence of items is no guaranteed, and will  not be preserved. Don't make any assumptions about the order objects are fetched from a dictionary. It is not specified and subject to change.

If you need an ordered collection, try using an array of single-element dictionaries, or an array of custom objects with a key and value property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following or come up with own data structure if you are worried about the position of elements inside a `Dictionary`

You can use `Array` of `key-value` pairs like this -> `[[String : AnyObject]]`. 
Which looks like : `[["New" : 1],["In Progress" : 3],...]`

You can also use tuples of `key` and `value` in an `Array` like this -> `[(key,value)]`
Which looks like : `[("New" , 1),("In Progress" , 3),...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get keys in this array

```
 NSArray *orderedArr =  [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```